# Как вернуть в исходное значение блок при параллакс эффекте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Когда мышка уходит из области эффекта параллакса, то объекты остаются там  же, а мне надо чтобы они возвращались в исходное состояние.

```js
// Yep, that's it!
$('#scene').parallax();
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.scene {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.layer:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.layer:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.30;
}

.layer:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.45;
}

.layer:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.60;
}

.layer:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.layer:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: 0.90;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <ul id="scene" class="scene">
    <li class="layer" data-depth="1.00"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer1.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.80"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer2.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.60"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer3.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.40"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer4.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.20"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer5.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.00"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer6.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/deploy/jquery.parallax.js"></script>

<!-- http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/ -->
```

Comment: вам нужно конкретно на этом примере? а то на разных реализациях `parallax` параметры разные.

Comment: Да, он легче, вот пытаюсь какой день, ничего не выходит, хоть бери и нанимай прогера написать заново параллакс скрипт, которого в сети нет....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам обновленный вариант вашего параллакса, я изменил `parallax.js` файл и добавил опцию контейнера, и теперь если дать такую опцию на `javascript` то эффект будет работать только при наведении мыши на данный контейнер.

Примечание:

> Контейнер можно дать только `javascript` элемент
>   Пример document.getElementById('simpleelement').

а это [ссылка](https://file.town/uploads/0vcu7v43r3oy6c61syj37qury.js) на скачивание обновленную библиотеку.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#scene').parallax({
        mouseport: document.getElementById('container')
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  margin: 0;
}
#container{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.scene {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.layer:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.layer:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0.30;
}

.layer:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 0.45;
}

.layer:nth-child(4) {
  opacity: 0.60;
}

.layer:nth-child(5) {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.layer:nth-child(6) {
  opacity: 0.90;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <ul id="scene" class="scene">
    <li class="layer" data-depth="1.00"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer1.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.80"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer2.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.60"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer3.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.40"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer4.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.20"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer5.png"></li>
    <li class="layer" data-depth="0.00"><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Lightweight-jQuery-Parallax-Engine-Parallax-js/examples/images/layer6.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://file.town/uploads/0vcu7v43r3oy6c61syj37qury.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен подойдет ли такая реализация, но где-то отсюда нужно копать:

```js
let enabled = true;
let body = document.body;
let allList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img'))

let parallax = (el, resistance, mouse) => {
  if(!enabled) {
    allList.forEach(element => element.classList.remove('away'));
    return enabled = true;
    
  }
  TweenLite.to(el, 0.4, {
    x: -((mouse.pageX - window.innerWidth / 2) / resistance),
    y: -((mouse.pageY - window.innerHeight / 2) / resistance),
    ease: Power0.easeNone
  }); 
};

body.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  enabled = false;  
  body.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    parallax('.background', -30, e);
    parallax('.cloud1', 10, e);
    parallax('.cloud2', 20, e);
    parallax('.cloud3', 30, e);
  })
})

body.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  enabled = false;    
    allList.forEach(el => {      
       setTimeout(function(){
         el.classList.add('away')
         el.removeAttribute('style');
       }, 400)            
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: Courier;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Courier;
}
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.header a {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

img.away {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: 300ms
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mouse-aware-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-and-TweenMax-Mouse-Parallax/images/background.jpg" alt="New York" class="background">
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mouse-aware-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-and-TweenMax-Mouse-Parallax/images/1.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud1">
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mouse-aware-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-and-TweenMax-Mouse-Parallax/images/2.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud2">
<img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mouse-aware-Parallax-Effect-with-jQuery-and-TweenMax-Mouse-Parallax/images/3.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud3">
```

Дело в том, что greensock, пока не дождется окончания своей анимации, "не разрешает" изменять атрибут style, т.е. сразу при событии mouseleave, не отработает removeAttribute('style'), например. Поэтому методом пробы, определил, что убрать атрибут style можно через 400ms, тогда все элементы возвращаются в "исходное положение". Но никак не могу понять как можно более плавно вернуть анимацию элементов, когда мышь снова входит в контейнер. Как бы там не было, возможно мой ответ подтолкнет на реализацию более правильного подхода.

Comment: Я вставил другой параллакс скрипт, он более понятен. Посмотри его, пожалуйста.