# Анимация движения картинки,когда по ней водят мышкой

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animation, parallax

Есть пример анимации https://themeisle.com/demo/?theme=Parallax%20One 
Как создать такое "движение" картинки?
Выяснил, что там используется `transform-style:preserve-3d` и несколько overlay картинок. А есть ли возможность сделать такое только с одной картинкой? Может какая-нибудь js либа?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679649/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5/679729?noredirect=1

Comment: @NeedHate Спасибо, но немного не то, там несколько элементов, а у меня задача шевелить одну картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать готовые библиотеки, для примера https://github.com/stephband/jparallax (демо и документация [здесь](http://stephen.band/jparallax/))

P.S. В вашем примере двигается 2 объекта.

Comment: Знаю, поэтому в вопросе и написано :"Выяснил, что там используется transform-style:preserve-3d и несколько overlay картинок. А есть ли возможность сделать такое только с одной картинкой? Может какая-нибудь js либа?"

Comment: так вы сделайте там только один слой

Comment: Но в любом случае спасибо, очень похоже на что-то подходящее)

Comment: вы также можете использовать js для слежения за мышкой как здесь http://fmrfox.com/slezhenie-za-kursorom/ но самому задать правила вычисления координат объекта

Comment: Да в общих чертах та либа, которую вы кидали, более чем реализаует то, что я хотел. Так что спасибо большое)